# How to count One2many and Many2one relation contents in odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

How can we count One2many  and many2one relation models contents in odoo10.
For example : One Faculty department has many departments. And Department has many faculties

Also how each head of department fetch his/her professors assigned or teaching under. Models listing below

Here is my code

***.py**

```py
_name = 'faculty.of.departments'
department_ids = fields.One2many('departments','dept_faculty_id', readonly=True)


_name = 'departments'
dept_faculty_id = fields.Many2one('faculty.of.departments','Faculty of Department', required=True, select=True)

_name = 'faculty'

department_id = fields.One2many('departments','faculty_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `len` on the field you want to count. For instance, to count the departments in a faculty you can do:

```
@api.model
def count_departments(self, faculty_id):
    return len(self.search([('id', '=', faculty_id)]).department_id)
```

or

```
@api.one
def count_departments(self):
    return len(self.department_id)
```

You can check the documentation to understand how the recordset works: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html

Comment: I want to count How many departments are under Faculty of department , for example : Faculty of Information & Telecom has 3 departments  (BS Computer Science , BS Computer Engineering, BS Computer Software ) ,